# 'PCA' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, pca, cross-validation, grid-search

I have an issue with my code:

PCA runs fine, but when I combine it with grid search I get this error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCYRo.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdoWZ.png)

This is my code:

```
pca = PCA()
param_grid = {'n_components': range(1,50)}
GridSearchCV(pca, param_grid, cv=5 ,scoring='f1', 
return_train_score=True, n_jobs=-1, 
error_score="raise").fit(prepared_data_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Please update the question to include the entire error traceback message.

Comment: *"estimator - estimator object
This is assumed to implement the scikit-learn estimator interface. Either estimator needs to provide a score function, or scoring must be passed."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout this:

remove scoring as F1 does not make sense for PCA by default.

Also, make sure to normalize your data before performing PCA; the reason is explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69157/why-do-we-need-to-normalize-data-before-principal-component-analysis-pca).

```
pca = PCA()

scaler = StandardScaler()


pipe = Pipeline(steps=[("scaler", scaler), ("pca", pca)])

param_grid = {'pca__n_components': range(1,50)}

search = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, cv=5 , return_train_score=True, n_jobs=-1, error_score="raise").fit(X_digits, y_digits)

print("Best parameter (CV score=%0.3f):" % search.best_score_)
print(search.best_params_)
```

here is a good example from documentation for further [exploration](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/putting_together.html).

Comment: I tried this and now I am getting this error: n_components=22 must be between 0 and min(n_samples, n_features)=21 with svd_solver='full'

Comment: you have put the number of components larger than your number of features. max possible for your set is 21 so use `param_grid = {'pca__n_components': range(1,21)}` @Maria-EleniIoannou